# How to implement Routing in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoprocessing

I need to add routing functionality in my application how to add the routing in openlayers.

Comment: Do mean by your own database or using web routing API?

Comment: Openlayers is just the 'canvas' - Datamodelling, processing has to be done elsewhere...

Answer (score 2):

There's an introduction to using pgRouting with OpenLayers here:
http://pgrouting.org/docs/foss4g2007/index.html

For further information you may also wish to see this question and answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794996/openstreetmap-data-with-openlayers-vs-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostGis database with pgRouting library.
Here is a nice tutorial for beginers on how to use pgRouting:
http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/

Here you have some more detailed information on how pgRouting functions work, it might be helpfull:
http://www.davidgis.fr/documentation/pgrouting-1.02/